# Is the use of "mistake" or "make mistake" or "do mistake" appropriate in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, do-vs-make

The following sentences sound the same to me. Do you see the mistake in it?

1. I always make mistakes when doing grammar exercises/answering questions;;
2. I always do mistakes when doing grammar exercises/answering questions;
3. I always mistake when doing grammar exercises/answering questions.

Comment: 3 "I always mistake something for something"… I always mistake cod for haddock… I always mistake sugar for salt… etc

Answer (score 9):

For me (1) "*make mistakes*" is the better phrasing. Also "*make a mistake*" if there is only one.

Phrase (3) does not read correctly. In that context "*mistake*" needs to be followed by the type of mistake. Eg "*I always mistake verbs for nouns when...*"

The only usage of (2) "*do mistakes*" I can think of is as a question, eg "*Do mistakes in grammar lead to ...?*"

The first line of the question asks "*Do you see the mistake in it?*" This also does not read nicely to me. Perhaps a better phrasing would be "*Do you see the differences between:*" or "*Can anyone [please] explain the differences in the following:*"

Comment: Even I don't favor 'do mistake'. But then, I think... we can use this to emphasize. Something like... *"It's not that experts are perfect in all sense; they **do** mistakes"*

Comment: @MaulikV "they do *make* mistakes" would sit better to my ear, I think. Adding the 'do' gives the emphasis to your sentence, but mistakes are 'made' not 'done' [ahh… as I notice Khan already said;)

Answer (score 7):

The sentence #1 is grammatically correct.

The sentence #2 isn't correct. You make mistakes, not do mistakes. However, you can do something by mistake. Sorry, I did it by mistake.

The sentence #3  also seems incorrect.  The verb "mistake" usually means to not understand or judge somebody/something correctly; you don't usually use it in the sense of making a mistake. For example, you mistook my meaning. I mistook you for my brother in this dress. However, according to The Free Dictionary, the verb "mistake" also means to make a mistake or error.

Answer (score 7):

**How do we define what is do-able?**

That which we do must be a *deed*.

**Did you do the deed?**

A "deed" is something which can be done *properly* or something which can be completed.

(Special placeholder cases are "something" and "nothing", where "thing" stands in for the deed.)

Thus, we cannot 'do' an error or 'do' a mistake because there is no proper way to do something improperly. We cannot act improperly properly. *Did you complete the error?* is a nonsensical question.

In contrast to *do*, which refers to engaging in an act that yields a deed, *to make* something is to bring it into being, to *cause* it.  There is no requirement that it be done properly or completely.

We can *make a mess* and *make an error* and *make a mistake*. All that is required of the thing that is *made* is that it be something we can bring into existence, something we can cause. The thing that is made *can* be something that can be made properly. But it doesn't have to be.

This explanation may in fact be a proper mess.